# nginx vs apache when returning XML files

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, xml

My head is tangled around this problem I have:

Here's a link to an XML file on nginx:
http://tag.sprtad.com/files/vast.xml

here's a link to an XML file on Apache
http://serve.sprtad.com/test.xml

This XML file is sort of a configuration file that can be tested here:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual

Just paste each of the links above in the textbox and click 'Test Ad'.
Below you could see 'Events' log.

The NGINX link, does not work, the tester returns:

```
(2:36:01 PM) Ads requested
(2:36:09 PM) adError Ad error (code 301): VAST wrapper redirect unwrapping timeout.
(2:36:09 PM) Error: VAST wrapper redirect unwrapping timeout.
```

The APACHE link, DO work, the tester returns:

```
(2:45:07 PM) Ads requested 
(2:45:08 PM) adsManagerLoaded 
(2:45:08 PM) adMetadata 
(2:45:09 PM) loaded  
(2:45:10 PM) Content Pause Requested  
(2:45:10 PM) Started  
(2:45:10 PM) impression
```

What can be the difference in handling the XML returned from both servers?

Comment: Either works for me in Chrome (version 42 on Windows 7 64-bit), though I do note it says that you should use https instead. I tried pasting the links, and the XML, so all four test inputs worked.

Comment: Is it resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a redirect is made if the http/1.0 is send.

Perhaps you can give some config details of nginx to validate where is the potential misstake.

Regards, Josef

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx server is outputting tab characters, it's possible the Ad tester doesn't handle this. This is visible if you pipe it through od, you'll see additional \t characters:

```
$ curl -s http://serve.sprtad.com/test.xml | od -c
```

The above shows no \t characters but the following does:

```
$ curl -s 'http://tag.sprtad.com/files/vast.xml' | od -c
```

It's possible that nginx and apache are handling it in different ways, but either way try removing the tab characters from the source, and replacing them with space characters which are more compatible.

Comment: Seems unlikly. On that site you can paste in the XML as one form of input. Either work.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem now as the nginx url seems to be working, and the tab characters are still there, so this wasn't the solution. You do need to be careful to retain the tab characters when copy-pasting though, i.e. by piping the curl output to pbcopy on OSX. Most terminals will convert to spaces.